# Want text to retain its position while expanding Mobile Menu

Tags: html, wordpress, css, genesis

In the following image there is a text called "VISITAR LA TIENDA", I want this to remain fixed even if I expand Mobile menu. I am using Genesis Magazine Pro Theme.

[image]

As you can see in the below image, it comes down when expanding Mobile Menu.

[image]

I am using this CSS code but it's not working

```
margin-top: -213px;
position: static;
margin-left: 200px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 27px;
```

Comment: Can you add specific CSS and a bit of HTML too?

Comment: I have added the images into the question, reworded title and content to improve grammar. You don't have to specify tools, library names in title because they can be added as part of tags. I have moved the name of theme that you are using into the content.

Comment: Hi Davide ,I am using specific class for "VISITAR LA TIENDA" but still it drops down ,here is the code    function after_header_text() {
    echo '<div id ="text1" class="title-text">VISITAR LA TIENDA</div>';
};
add_action('genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap', 'after_header_text');    ,This is the site I am working on http://www.passiveincomekube.com/violeta/

Answer (score 0):

Try these styles for the heading:

```
.title-text { 
    top: 205px; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%, 
    text-align: center, 
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You'll want to adjust spacing etc on mobile views although that's easily done through media queries.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thanks for reply but it's not working ,it again coming below when I click on Mobile Menu Icon , This is my website http://www.passiveincomekube.com/violeta/

Comment: I've just had a look at your website; is there any chance you could output the title text inside `<div class="wrap">` or is there a reason you've not done it that way?

Comment: hi, I am using Genesis Theme ,In that ,I think there is only way to add text using hooks ,I think there is no way I can add title text inside `<div class="wrap">` I am not expert in this theme, if there is I dnt know ,open to suggestions ,here is reference to genesis hooks http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/

Comment: Just updated original post, should do what you need.

Comment: HI Daniel ,Thanks for reply ,I used this code and it worked but I want text to be in middle and when I use `top: 235px;` The Mobile menu does not expand and it's pointer does not come when hover over to it ,is there any solution to this ,if yes ,it would work perfectly

Comment: Just had a quick look at your site again, make sure you have `z-index: -1;` in the stylesheet for `.title-text` and it should work fine.

Comment: Worked perfectly ,Thanks a lot Daniel